# Google chrome bug, disrupts the kernel update

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

In the middle of the update it throws me this exception

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  401  Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a warning (that's what the `W:` in front of it means), and it doesn't disrupt anything other than not receiving upgrade information for Google Chrome. In particular, it won't prevent kernel upgrades.

You can either continue on to whatever you were going to do next or try `sudo apt-get update` again to try to get Chrome upgrade information.